# Rails: Determining RESTful http method by action type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I'm just wondering if rails has any inbuilt way of determining the correct http method (get, post, put, delete) by the action name(?)

So, for example, if I were to enter "new" as the action, is there any way rails can realise it ought request via "get"?

If not, a second problem...I tried manually creating a hash that mapped restful actions to their default methods - specifically:

```
actionhash = {
  :index => get,
  :show => get,
  :new => get,
  :create => post,
  :edit => get,
  :update => put,
  :delete => delete
}
```

That hash is then called with (if action = :show for example)

```
actionhash[action] action, :id => 123
```

The difficulty is when I create a hash with 'get' values, it comes back with:

> undefined local variable or method `get' for #>

So, assuming there's no inbuilt way of determining the correct method, how can I enter http methods into a hash?

Comment: Where are you going to put this code? What's the goal?

Comment: Rspec matchers for restful resources

Comment: I don't understand WHY you want to do this, but if you want to make that hash you should make them either symbols or strings. `:index => :get` or `:index => 'get'` etc.

Comment: @mischa: ... and call it like this: send(actionhash[action], action, :id => 123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
actionhash = {
  :index => :get,
  :show => :get,
  :new => :get,
  :create => :post,
  :edit => :get,
  :update => :put,
  :delete => :delete
}

send(actionhash[action], :id => 123)
```

Ugly, though.